# How do I create a scheduler so that my nft is sent according to the schedule?

Tags: python, brownie

I would like to implement posting my paintings at 12 o'clock on weekdays using cron. I have implemented everything through brownie
and just specify

- 12 1-5 * * brownie run /my full folder
  doesn't work, I get an error brownie: command not found

Comment: Is the command installed on your computer ? Also, it's hard to help with this much information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set up cron jobs in Brownie or Solidity. Actually, Ethereum as a whole does not natively support this kind of operation.

You have to use an automation protocol that runs on top of Ethereum. For instance, take a look at [Gelato Network](https://www.gelato.network/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Chainlink Keeper Network](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/) to work with a decentralized cron-like application.

You could 100% use a solution like cron, but it would be a bit wonky. The error you're running into with cron is likely something unrelated to brownie or solidity.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I assume the error is related to calling run /scrypts/create.py from a folder, specifically when I create a cron with this view:
HOME=/home/denis/project/dnft/
SHELL=/home/denis/.local/bin/brownie
12 * 1-5 * * * brownie run scripts/create.py --network rinkyb 
When I call systemctl status cron
I get a "brownie --help" message and that's it

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get crontab working with Brownie. Here's my workaround:

Use a Python scheduler such as schedule, apschedule or timeloop from within the script that you want Brownie to run, then simply run Brownie from the command line. Below is a code example of the first option, schedule.

```
import schedule
import time

def post_paintings():
    [your code]

def main():
    # schedule the job to run at 12 o'clock
    schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(post_paintings)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

At the command line use: brownie run scripts/this_script.py --network xxxx